# In Ruby, why does a equality with nil ("Date.new == nil") return nil?

Tags: ruby, date, equality

When writing some rspec today, I came across some unexpected behavior with comparing Date (and Time) instances to nil.  Here's a sample using raw ruby (no Rails or other libraries):

```
user@MacBook-Work ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
user@MacBook-Work ~ $ irb
>> 1 == nil
=> false
>> "string" == nil
=> false
>> :sym == nil
=> false
>> false == nil
=> false
>> [] == nil
=> false
>> {} == nil
=> false
>> Proc.new {} == nil
=> false
```

So far, so good, right?

```
>> Date.new == nil
=> nil
>> Time.new == nil
=> nil
```

Date does implement its own ===, which works fine:

```
>> Date.new === nil
=> false
```

Is there any explanation as to why this happens or why this is desired behavior? == seems to be implemented from Comparable.==, however documentation on that doesn't given any indication that it would ever return nil.  What's the design decision to this?

Update! This is not the case in 1.9.2:

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > Date.new == nil
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > Time.new == nil
 => false
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I checked the source and here's what I found out:

The comparison operators defined by Comparable all use the function `rb_cmpint` together with `<=>`. `rb_cmpint` raises an exception when one of the operands is nil.

So the operators of Comparable raise an exception if the rhs is not comparable to the lhs. I.e. `5 < 2` is false, but `5 < "la"` raises an exception. They do this to differentiate between cases where `<` is not true because the rhs is smaller and cases where it's not true because the rhs is not comparable. Or in other words: When `x < y` is false that implies that `x >= y` is true. So in cases where that would not be the case, it throws an exception.

`==` raising an exception would be bad, because `==` usually does not (and should not) require its operands to be comparable. However `==` uses the same method as the other operands, which does raise an exception. So the whole function is simply wrapped in an `rb_rescue`. And that returns `nil` if an exception is thrown.

Note that this only applies to ruby 1.8. This has been fixed in 1.9 and now `==` never returns `nil` (except of course if you define your own `==` that does).

Comment: FWIW, 1.8.7 (and possibily earlier) raises ArgumentError in the comparison example you gave:

  >> 5 < "la"
  ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
   from (irb):41:in `<'
   from (irb):41

However, your explanation does make sense, and it seems Date#<=> was never updated (on purpose? who knows!) to raise instead of return nil.

I guess my main beef now is with the (all too typically) terse Ruby docs which don't mention this behavior:
* http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000673
* http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html (no mention of 'nil' on the page)

Comment: Came here because I'm working my way through [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), which include the question "Is it better to use obj.nil?  or  obj == nil # Why?" I hope there's a better answer than "nil? is better because it's less buggy".

Answer (score 7):

If you're depending on this for code, you can always use the .nil? method which any Ruby Object responds to.

```
>> Date.new.nil?
=> false
```

Comment: Personally, on reading this, I'm never going to use '== nil' again!

Answer (score 4):

The Date class includes the `Comparable#==` method, but that method invokes the `<=>` method of the receiver. In this case that's `Date#<=>`, which expects another Date object. When it receives `nil` it returns `nil`. This behavior certainly seems inconsistent, and I don't know the reasons behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you can't compare things that are not defined. It's desirable because if at least one of your operands is not defined then you can't draw any conclusion about the result, which is different from asserting truth.

A lot of languages treat nil and false the same, which is suspect is purely for convenience. It's certainly not mathematically correct.

Comment: If this were the reason, then this would only apply when comparing with nil. That is not the case. You get nil when you compare a comparable object against anything that isn't of the same type, so for example Date.new == [1,2,3] returns nil as well (except in 1.9 where == never returns nil).

Comment: Good point. How about "it happens because you can't compare two objects of different type, a subset of this being a comparison with nil." :) The OP asked why you can't compare with nil, and I believe my answer is correct in that context; however, it is not the whole reason.